# Lua tables: performance hit for starting array indexing at 0?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm porting FFT code from Java to Lua, and I'm starting to worry a bit about the fact that in Lua the array part of a table starts indexing at 1 while in Java array indexing starts at 0.

For the input array this causes no problem because the Java code is set up to handle the possibility that the data under consideration is not located at the start of the array. However, all of the working arrays internal to the code are assumed to starting indexing at 0. I know that the code will work as written -- Lua tables are awesome like that -- but I have no sense at all about the performance hit I might incur by having the "0" element of the array going into the hash table part of the underlying C structure (or indeed, if that is what will happen).

My question: is this something worth worrying about? Should I be planning to profile and hand-optimize the code? (The code will eventually be used to transform many relatively small (> 100 time points) signals of varying lengths not known in advance.)

Comment: Starting worrying after profiling shows you need to. I suspect you won't need to worry.

Comment: my understanding from the Lua documentation is that there is not really a array construct.  Tables can be used as arrays however the index value is really just a key.  I am not sure of the underlying representation though I remember reading something about integer keys are stored in one area and string keys are stored hashed.  You can use an integer key of zero (0) which is not the same as "0".  See http://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html and see http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial

Comment: However this FAQ http://www.luafaq.org/gotchas.html#T6 says that an integer index of zero (0) will be put into the hashed portion of the table.  However there is no date.  This document describes Lua performance tips including use of tables.  http://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf

Comment: In LuaJIT, elements at `0` will be put into the array part of the table.

Comment: Bottom line, tables are as efficient as they can be made to be, since (nearly) everything that isn't a simple scalar value in Lua is a table. The "array part" is an optimization, and there is no cost to keys that are in the array part from having keys that don't fall in the array part.

Comment: @RBerteig, just to clarify, when I wrote "performance hit", I just meant to refer to the extra access-time caused by storing a value in the hash-table part over and above the access-time for a value in the optimized array part.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, That's nice to know! Alas, I'm not sure if LuaJIT is an option for me. To make a long story short, I'd rather develop my code in R -- what can I say, I'm a statistician -- but it needs to run in a cross-platform mobile app developed in Xamarin. I'm resorting to Lua because, like R, it's interpreted and duck-typed, which qualities allow a faster code/run/tweak cycle than does C#. So I'm using NLua, which uses KeraLua, which uses KopiLua; I don't know if/how I might make use of LuaJIT in this setup.

Answer (score 3):

I have made small, probably not that reliable, test:

```
local arr = {}
for i=0,10000000 do
  arr[i] = i*2
end

for k, v in pairs(arr) do
  arr[k] = v*v
end
```

And similar version with 1 as the first index. On my system:

```
$ time lua example0.lua
real  2.003s

$ time lua example1.lua
real  2.014s
```

I was also interested how table.insert will perform

```
for i=1,10000000 do
  table.insert(arr, 2*i)
...
```

and, suprisingly

```
$ time lua example2.lua
real 6.012s
```

Results:
Of course, it depends on what system you're running it, probably also whic lua version, but it seems that it makes little to no difference between zero-start and one-start. Bigger difference is caused by the way you insert things to array.

Comment: The loop with `table.insert` was bound to be slower because of global lookups, function calls, and the computation of the length of `arr` each time. But note that the loop with `table.insert` is 10 times longer...

Comment: The 10 times longer part was a typo :).

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer in this case is changing the algorithm so that everything is indexed with 1. And consider that part of the conversion.

Your FFT will be less surprising to another Lua user (like me), given that all "array-like" tables are indexed by one.

It might not be as stressful as you might think, given the way numeric loops are structured in Lua (where the "start" and the "end" are "inclusive"). You would be exchanging this:

```
for i=0,#array-1 do
  ... (do stuff with i)
end
```

By this:

```
for i=1,#array do
  ... (do stuff with i)
end
```

The non-numeric loops would remain unchanged (except that you will be able to use `ipairs` too, if you so desire).

Comment: This would involve going through all of the for-, while-, and repeat-loops in 6,600 lines of code and figuring out which indices need to be changed, and how, by hand (many of the loop indices are used to set the values of other indices and assigned values). The only reason that I decided on the port at all was because I could do most of it algorithmically with only a bit of work by hand; time constraints rule out anything more involved, so this answer is a non-starter for me.

Comment: My point is that you have to go through the loops anyway, when translating from Java to Lua.

Comment: Not by hand I don't. I wrote code to do all of the translations.

Comment: That's even better then! You can change the code to change all loops in one go :)

Comment: What we've got here is... failure to communicate. Translating for-loops from Java to Lua is one-to-one. Maintaining correctness while trying to munge the actual contents of the loops is not feasible. It's basically the difference between a fairly simple string replacement and actually writing my own lexer and parser to run on the entire codebase.

Comment: (By "translating for-loops" above, I mean, e.g., replacing the Java loop statement specified by the string "for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i += 2) {" with the Lua loop statement specified by the string "for i = 0,(floor(n/2) - 1),2 do".)